# Can I Enable Activity hot corner in Full screen apps?

Tags: fullscreen, activities-overview, gnome-shell

I want to enable top left hot corner that triggers activities view in full screen apps.

**More Details**

generally when you take your mouse pointer to the top left corner of the screen in gnome shell is triggers the *Activity View* where we can manage open windows and work-spaces, and it's a great way to multitask only using mouse (while <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> requires you to use keyboard), but the limitation is that it only works with non full screen apps. it does't work in full screen YouTube or other web pages or video in full screen or photos. I want it to work with full screen apps, is it possible? if *Yes* then how can I implement it?

Ubuntu Gnome 16.10

**Update**

This works in KDE (kubuntu) that makes it possible to do.

Comment: I think new Gnome uses Mutter Display manager instead of Compiz, can you tell me how to do this with mutter? or do i need to install Compiz as my default window manager

Comment: @JacobVlijm activities from cli?

Comment: Nah, forget it, I can't check.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko preesing the Super key is a solution, but not as good as slide of mouse or touchpad

Comment: Any way of doing this in 18.04?